# Global require with Browserify v2

Tags: javascript, module, browserify

I want to use Browserify to bundle my files, but I then need to require one of the modules inside of my Browserify bundled `bundle.js` on the HTML page itself. This is currently not possible because there is no `require` function defined on the page.

It appears that the `require` function defined by browserify in `bundle.js` is inside of an IIFE, so I can't use that. Is it possible to throw this one out in place of a global `require`?

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
  // Require the `app` module inside of `bundle.js`
  var app = require('app');
  app.start();
</script>
```

I need to do this because my `app.start` function requires some JSON is passed to it which can only be rendered by the server-side template.

N.B. I am using Browserify v2.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use `-r` to [expose a global `require()`](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires) function for the files you specify:

x.js:

```
module.exports = function (n) { return n * 111 }
```

Console

```
$ browserify -r ./x.js > bundle.js
```

then in your html:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    var x = require('./x.js');
    console.log(x(3))
</script>
```

will print `333`.

In your case, just do `browserify -r app` to expose `require('app')` to the external context.

Comment: Thanks for this. Oddly if you pass a relative URL like `x.js` instead of `./x.js`, it errors with `TypeError: Not a string or buffer`

Comment: You've got to pass the path exactly because module resolution happens at bundle time. There is no module solution algorithm in the client bundles anymore in v2.

Comment: I'd like to have the require method be attached to the global returned from the built module, giving me encapsulation. Something like ```bundle.require('./x.js')```. I've done is by creating a manifest of requires in my main file. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm nervous about having the global `require` because I'm writing software that is meant to be embedded onto other sites. A different implementation of `require` will probably be defined on at least some of the sites.

Comment: The browserify documentation states that browserify will fall back to any previously defined require function, so it may be that it won't interfere with others, as long as paths don't collide.

Comment: For some reason, when I use a similar command, the module gets exported without the leading dot (I have to use require("/x.js");)  Any idea why that might be?